# Swift : An array of [String : NSImage]

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsimage

I'm trying to create a array of **`dictionary<String,NSImage>`**,
so I do this:

```
class PreferencesController : NSObject{

var generalImage = NSImage(named: "NSAdvanced");
var textEditingImage = NSImage(named: "NSFontPanel");
var GUIImage = NSImage(named: "NSColorPanel");

var preferencesOptionTableList : NSMutableArray = [
    ["name":"General"],
    ["name":"Text Editing"],
    ["name":"GUI"]];

var preferencesOptionTableImageList : [[String:NSImage]] = [["image":textEditingImage]];
}
```

But I got this error:

```
PreferencesController.Type does not have a member named 
'textEditingImage'
```

Please help me I still don't know what to do after a hour of search

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible problems:

1. *textEditingImage* is most likely an optional *NSImage?*, not *NSImage*, which will most likely be a problem when you put it into the dictionary. I suspect you will need to unwrap it first.
2. The *var preferencesOptionTableList : NSMutableArray...*  should be split into declaration and definition and the definition moved to init, possibly like this:

   ```
   class PreferencesController: NSObject {


   var textEditingImage:NSImage = NSImage(named: "NSFontPanel")!

   var preferencesOptionTableImageList : [[String:NSImage]]

   override init() {
       preferencesOptionTableImageList = [["image":textEditingImage]]
       super.init()
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.  I tried this "var preferencesOptionTableImageList = [NSDictionary(object: textEditingImage?, forKey: "image")];
" but still the same error

Comment: @Ql HaoYan, adding a ? at the end of an optional only unwraps it for chained events. Try var textEditingImage = NSImage(named: "NSFontPanel")!

Comment: Also, note remove the ; at the end of all your statements and you don't have to specify constant or variable types unless you HAVE to specify them.... Swift is not Obj-C

Comment: That works, thank you very much. But I'm wondering why when I put "preferencesOptionTableImageList = [["image":textEditingImage]]" out of "init()" I got error "expected declaration"